# getUserMedia block reload page after user change

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia

Is it possible to detect that the user has 'enabled' the microphone/video for the webpage without having to get the user to refresh the page manually after an access denied & manual user enable?

basically it is disabled, when the user enables it I want to refresh the page automatically.

```
navigator.getUserMedia (
   // constraints
   {
      video: true,
      audio: true
   },

   // successCallback
   function(localMediaStream) {
      var video = document.querySelector('video');
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
      video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
         // Do something with the video here.
      };
   },

   // errorCallback
   function(err) {
    if(err === PERMISSION_DENIED) {
      // Explain why you need permission and how to update the permission setting

    }
   }
);
```

Comment: Why refresh the page? Why not just try `getUserMedia` again (on some interval)?

Comment: because the chrome extension says need to refresh after making a change. the problem is capturing a user change. (the above code doesn't when rerun)

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Because I'm facing the same thing now.